# Extract all Product database in a single List<Product> with CommerceTools SDK v2

Tags: java, commercetools

I'm looking for a way to migrate certain functionality from CommerceTools Java SDK-v1 to SDK-v2.
This functionality allows me to extract the entire product database (around 30k products) into a single list of products (`List<Product>`).

This is the code we currently use with SDK v1:

```
            final QueryPredicate qPred = ProductQuery.of().productType().isInIds(ids);
            final ProductQuery seedQuery = ProductQuery.of()
                .withSort(m -> m.id().sort().asc())
                .withLimit(ProjectConstants.PAGE_SIZE)
                .withPredicates(qPred)
                .withFetchTotal(false);
            final CompletionStage<List<Product>> resultStage = findNext(seedQuery, seedQuery, new LinkedList<>(), connCT);
            final List<Product> actualProducts = resultStage.toCompletableFuture().join();
            final List<Product> javaSortedActual = actualProducts.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getId())).collect(toList());
            return javaSortedActual;
```

As you can see, `ProductQuery` is used to create the seedQuery that is then used with `CompletionStage.findNext` which is the command that retrieves all the product pages one by one and enters them into the complete list.

The problem is that with the SDK v2 the `ProductQuery` method no longer exists and I no longer know how I should recover all the products from our database in a single list.

Does anyone know how I can get the same functionality with SDK v2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the QueryUtils class with it's methods. They provide similar functionality.

```
    public void queryAll() {
    ProjectApiRoot apiRoot = createProjectClient();
    List<String> ids = QueryUtils.queryAll(apiRoot.productProjections().get(), (productProjections) -> {
        return productProjections.stream().map(ProductProjection::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }, 100)
            .thenApply(lists -> lists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .toCompletableFuture()
            .join();
    }
```

Please see https://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-sdk-java-v2/javadoc/com/commercetools/docs/meta/Querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @jenschude, but I finally decided to create my own method because I needed to add the complete Product objects in a List to process them later.
It may not be the best solution, but it works for me, which is the important thing :-)

```java
    public List<Product> getAllProductsByPredicate(final String predicate) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Product> tmpProducts = new java.util.ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList());
        boolean lastPage = false;
        int pagina = 0;

        try {
            // Instead of using offset to get a page, ask for elements being greater than the id of the first
            // product in your project
            String lastId = getApiRoot()
                .products()
                .get()
                .withWhere(predicate)
                .withSort("id asc")
                .withLimit(1)
                .execute()
                .toCompletableFuture().get()
                .getBody().getResults().get(0).getId();
            lastId = lastId.substring(0, lastId.length() - 1) + "0"; // Starting last id less than the first one

            while (!lastPage) {
                pagina++;
                ProductPagedQueryResponse productPagedQueryResponse =
                    getApiRoot()
                        .products()
                        .get()
                        // Important, internally we use id > $lastId, it will not work without this line
                        .withSort("id asc")
                        .withWhere(predicate)
                        .addWhere("id > :lastId")
                        .addPredicateVar("lastId", lastId)
                        // Limit the size per page
                        .withLimit(MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_RESULTS)
                        // always use this
                        .withWithTotal(false)
                        .execute()
                        .toCompletableFuture()
                        .get()
                        .getBody();

                // Add all the results to temporary list os products
                tmpProducts.addAll(productPagedQueryResponse.getResults());
                // Evaluate the size of current results
                int size = productPagedQueryResponse.getResults().size();
                if (size != 0) {
                    LOGGER.debug("Recuperada la página #{} con {} productos", pagina, size);
                    lastId = productPagedQueryResponse.getResults().get(size - 1).getId();
                }
                // If (size < MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_RESULTS) then lastPage = true to exit the loop
                if (size != MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_RESULTS) {
                    LOGGER.debug("Ultima página de productos (total {} páginas)", pagina);
                    lastPage = true;
                }
            }
            return tmpProducts;
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to execute. ExecutionException:\n{}", e1.getMessage());
            return tmpProducts;
        }
    }
```

Thanks again